# In stm32, when I use any function in the HAL library in while, it enters while only once

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide, cmsis

The software does not stand up when I use any function from the Hal library. It goes into While only once and then does nothing.

I reinstalled the project, made all the settings again and got the same result. I also deleted the library, downloaded the library again and set up a new project, but again I could not get a different result.

> **This code is working**

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
int counter=0;
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

#ifndef HSEM_ID_0
#define HSEM_ID_0 (0U) /* HW semaphore 0*/
#endif
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */
/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_0 */
  int32_t timeout;
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_1 */
  /* Wait until CPU2 boots and enters in stop mode or timeout*/
  timeout = 0xFFFF;
  while((__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_D2CKRDY) != RESET) && (timeout-- > 0));
  if ( timeout < 0 )
  {
  Error_Handler();
  }
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_1 */
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_2 */
/* When system initialization is finished, Cortex-M7 will release Cortex-M4 by means of
HSEM notification */
/*HW semaphore Clock enable*/
__HAL_RCC_HSEM_CLK_ENABLE();
/*Take HSEM */
HAL_HSEM_FastTake(HSEM_ID_0);
/*Release HSEM in order to notify the CPU2(CM4)*/
HAL_HSEM_Release(HSEM_ID_0,0);
/* wait until CPU2 wakes up from stop mode */
timeout = 0xFFFF;
while((__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_D2CKRDY) == RESET) && (timeout-- > 0));
if ( timeout < 0 )
{
Error_Handler();
}
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      counter++;

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_DIRECT_SMPS_SUPPLY);

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

> İt doesn't work here, the only difference is that there is no Hal_Delay function

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
int counter=0;
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

#ifndef HSEM_ID_0
#define HSEM_ID_0 (0U) /* HW semaphore 0*/
#endif
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */
/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_0 */
  int32_t timeout;
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_0 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_1 */
  /* Wait until CPU2 boots and enters in stop mode or timeout*/
  timeout = 0xFFFF;
  while((__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_D2CKRDY) != RESET) && (timeout-- > 0));
  if ( timeout < 0 )
  {
  Error_Handler();
  }
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_1 */
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
/* USER CODE BEGIN Boot_Mode_Sequence_2 */
/* When system initialization is finished, Cortex-M7 will release Cortex-M4 by means of
HSEM notification */
/*HW semaphore Clock enable*/
__HAL_RCC_HSEM_CLK_ENABLE();
/*Take HSEM */
HAL_HSEM_FastTake(HSEM_ID_0);
/*Release HSEM in order to notify the CPU2(CM4)*/
HAL_HSEM_Release(HSEM_ID_0,0);
/* wait until CPU2 wakes up from stop mode */
timeout = 0xFFFF;
while((__HAL_RCC_GET_FLAG(RCC_FLAG_D2CKRDY) == RESET) && (timeout-- > 0));
if ( timeout < 0 )
{
Error_Handler();
}
/* USER CODE END Boot_Mode_Sequence_2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      counter++;
      HAL_Delay(250);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_DIRECT_SMPS_SUPPLY);

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

It only works when there is a counter variable. But when I write the state delay function, the counter changes only once.

I did it in the SysTick setting as you mentioned in the comments. But still the result did not change.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at the very least the code where you call the HAL functions. Without seeing what you do, it is unlikely that anyone can provide useful hints.

Comment: `into While only once and then does nothing` How are you checking that? How do you know? `In stm32` What stm32? `I reinstalled the project` What project and how did you reinstall it? `downloaded the library again` what library and from where did you download? `It only works` What "works"? What does it mean that something "works" in this context? `HAL_Delay(250);` did you initialize SysTick interrupt?

Comment: I'm checking it from Live Expressions.

Comment: That code does not have any observable output. How would you know whether `HAL_Delay` actually delays execution or not? Your compiler might just remove the whole `counter` thing. Maybe you can make it `volatile` to avoid that.

Comment: If `counter` is only incremented once, that might mean that `HAL_Delay` just never returns. It doesn't mean that it works once. Maybe you missed to initialized some timer (I am not familiar with stm32).

Comment: "It only works when there is a counter variable. But when I write the state delay function, the counter changes only once." That does not make any sense. If there is no `counter` variable how would `counter` only change once? Please rewrite and show code that "works" together with the code that "doesn't work"

Comment: I shared the working version and the non-working version.

Answer (score 0):

`HAL_Delay()` requires that you have some code that periodically calls `HAL_IncTick()` to increment the counter that `HAL_Delay()` uses to measure time.  Typically, `HAL_IncTick()` is called from the `SysTick` ISR.  Also you should call `HAL_Init()` to initialize the HAL before using the HAL.

You should read the HAL User Manual for more details.  Here are some relevant excerpts.

> **Why do I need to configure the SysTick timer to use the HAL drivers?** The SysTick timer is configured to be used to generate
> variable increments by calling HAL_IncTick() function in SysTick ISR
> and retrieve the value of this variable by calling HAL_GetTick()
> function. The call HAL_GetTick() function is mandatory when using HAL
> drivers with Polling Process or when using HAL_Delay().
>
> **What programming model sequence should I follow to use HAL drivers ?** Follow the sequence below to use the APIs provided in the HAL
> drivers:
>
> 1. Call HAL_Init() function to initialize the system (data cache, NVIC priority,…).
> 2. Initialize the system clock by calling HAL_RCC_OscConfig() followed by HAL_RCC_ClockConfig().
> 3. Add HAL_IncTick() function under SysTick_Handler() ISR function to enable polling process when using HAL_Delay() function
> 4. Start initializing your peripheral by calling HAL_PPP_Init().
> 5. Implement the hardware low level initialization (Peripheral clock, GPIO, DMA,..) by calling HAL_PPP_MspInit() instm32l4xx_hal_msp.c
> 6. Start your process operation by calling IO operation functions.

Comment: @Enes Regarding the new code you added to the question, you don't show whether `HAL_IncTick()` is called from the SysTick ISR.  Set a breakpoint on `HAL_IncTick()` to see if it is ever called.  If not then that could explain why `HAL_Delay()` never returns.